# Oracle Stored Procedures without Ref Cursors

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of a way to call an Oracle 19 stored procedure in C# without the command object requiring an implicit Ref Cursor be created?

I have no need for any output from this procedure.

It just deletes records that are more than 2 hours old from a table - maybe there's some there - maybe not. There never is any output that I need back from this procedure.

When I try to execute it:

```
OraCommand.CommandText = sql;
OraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i += 2)
{
    OraCommand.Parameters.Add(args[i], OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = args[i+1];
}

try
{
    OraConn.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}

int RowsAffected = OraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get this error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

The command object contains this error:

> OraCommand.ImplicitRefCursors' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Does anybody know why?
Thanks

Comment: Your code sample is not complete - it does not show creating OraConn and OraCommand objects.

Comment: It would be normal to execute the command inside the try block, so it will not be executed if opening the connection fails.

Comment: The connection object opens fine and if I put it inside the Try/Catch it masks the problem inside the command object - only shows the "Operation not valid due to state"  - the problem with it's state is that I have not created a Ref Cursor.